# Space on right side of html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table coded here (only tried on Firefox) and I have a problem with it. There is white space or just space on the right side of the table, and I don't know what the problem is.

http://jsfiddle.net/darkangel8xt/qZ8Gu/

There is space and I don't know why.

Please tell me what is wrong, why it's doing it, and how to fix it. Nothing more.

Comment: I just see black space...? I don't see anything wrong, you have to be more specific. You mean the gap between the links and the top of your object...? (*sidenote - Tables are evil for non-tabular data...*)

Comment: @NicholasHazel The black is the body, which is the background I set it on. I'm as specific as I can be. Extra space on RIGHT SIDE of the TABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing a `</td>` tag -- you had it as a `<td>` instead, and that made the browser render a new cell. Correcting it fixes the whitespace issue.

```
</td>
<td class="image">
    <img src="deadlink" alt="" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ8Gu/2/

Comment: Thank you! I would have never found that.

Comment: I thought it looked better the other way... with the padding on the left due to the `border-radius`. Oh well.

Comment: @NicholasHazel You were looking at one of the cells, not the table. Inside the table everything was fine.